# HTML form input element not capturing all text characters on iOS (iPhone / iPad)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, filereader, data-uri

I have an HTML form with input and file elements. The user can upload an image and a data URL for that image will be generated using JavaScript's file reader. A small preview of the uploaded image will then show up on the screen with its data URL passed in as the image source.

The data URL will also be passed in as a value for an input element in the form.

Upon form submission, the data URL will be stored in a database. The user can then view an image gallery with all of the uploaded images (which will be accessed through the stored data URLs).

Everything works fine when uploading images from my laptop. However, the problem occurs when I upload large images from my iPhone and iPad. When uploading large images from my iPhone and iPad, only a small part of the data URL gets inserted as the input tag's value, and as a result, only a small part of the image gets rendered when viewing it in the image gallery. The image preview that shows up on the form page is fine on iOS - I can view the entire image there. I am just not able to submit the data URL, a long string of text (sometimes nearing a million characters) in its entirety. I have not set a maxlength value in my input tag, so I can't help but feel like there is some predefined maxlength value for html input tags on iOS.

Again, I have no problems uploading large images from my laptop - the entire data URL gets passed through and stored in the database. I am able to view all images uploaded from my laptop clearly and fully in the image gallery on all devices. I am just not able to upload large images in their entirety from iOS (iPhone/iPad).

Why could this be happening? And how can I ensure that the entire data URL gets passed in as the input tag's value on iOS?

Comment: is this web or mobile app ?

Comment: @AlanYong web. its a website which can be accessed through a browser on desktop/laptop and smartphone/tablet

Comment: is it because you convert the image to other format like `blob` or `base64` ?

Comment: Yes, I am converting the image to base64 to generate a data URI/data URL after it is uploaded in the client side using Javascript. I am facing no problems converting the image to base64, just with transferring all of the base64 data (which is quite long) to the website backend on form submit. @AlanYong

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't convert image to `base64` to upload. The string size of `base64` is too huge for mobile browser and somehow it will automatically convert to smaller and cause the image out of shape. Mobile browser can't handle huge size file `string` or `json`. More information you can refers to https://medium.com/snapp-mobile/dont-use-base64-encoded-images-on-mobile-13ddeac89d7c ; not my article though

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I cannot convert the image to blob or any other binary data type due to restrictions with the programming language I am using for the backend. It seems like I can create a blob string to store image data, so I will look into that.